# Unconditional result for the existence of primes in intervals of length one

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, pigeonhole-principle

Dusart proved in 2010 that there's at least one prime between $x$ and $\left(1 + \frac{1}{25\ln^2x}\right)x$ for $x \geq 396738$

My **question** is: Is Dusart's *the smallest* known interval with at least one prime?

Secondly, Is there is an unconditional result for the existence of primes in intervals of lenght **one**, i.e., given $a>0$ and $b>0$, such that $b-a=1$, then find conditions on $a$ and $b$ in which there exist a prime $p$ verifying $a<p<b$.

Comment: Not to ask a stupid question, but what do you mean by intervals of length one? I'm sure you're not asking asking whether every integer (or at least one of every two integers) is prime, or for some criterion for such to hold true...

Comment: @peterag: This is not a stupid question. I am asking on the existence of a prime in intervals of lenght 1, eg, $2.8<3<3.8$.

Comment: Then, again, to be clear, you are not asking can there exist a lower bound $L$ such that $x \ge L$ implies that there is a prime in the interval $(x, x +1 )$? What do you have mind?

Comment: @peterag: Yes. This is not my question. My question is: given $a>0$ and $b>0$, such that $b-a=1$, then find conditions on $a$ and $b$ in which there exist a prime $p$ verifying $a<p<b$.

Comment: After the last edit... It seems to me you are asking "when is an integer prime?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asymptotically smallest known interval which always contains a prime for sufficiently large $x$ is $[x, x + x^{0.525 + o(1)}]$, by a result of Baker, Harman and Pintz.

This is considerably smaller than Dusart, but it is somewhat inexplicit.  I am not sure if someone has done the work to extract a concrete, explicit constant from their paper, although it should be possible in principle.

Conjecturally, we believe that the smallest interval is more like $[x,x + O((\log x)^{2+o(1)})]$, which would be exponentially smaller still.

Your second question makes very little sense.  The only time there is a prime in the open interval $(a,a+1)$ is when $a$ is a non-integer that rounds up to a prime.  It would be impossible to give a more generic condition than that.

Answer (score 0):

The prime number theorem implies that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that for all $x > N$, there exists a prime between $x$ and $x(1 + \epsilon)$.

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question. Dusart's bound is stronger than $(1+o(1))x$ (indeed it ought to be stronger, since it's based on explicit calculations and bounds on zeros of the Riemann zeta function, whereas PNT only requires that $\zeta$ is non-vanishing on the absissa $\sigma=1$).

Comment: FYI: PNT itself is much stronger than $(1+\epsilon)$ though I did not bother to out it in exact terms.

Comment: PNT cannot promise any better than $(1+O(1/\ln^2 x))x$, making it weaker than Dusart which explicitly provides the exact terms that you didn't bother to write :).  So this still doesn't do anything to address the OP's question, which asks if there exists any interval *shorter* than Dusart.

Comment: Right but this is not directly apparent from the PNT because $O\Big(\frac{1}{\ln^2 x}\Big)$ of the PNT doesn't directly make it weaker than Dusart's results because $\frac{1}{\ln^2 x} = o(1)$. We need to work out the $O$ constant before making the above claim.

Comment: I should be more explicit: it is possible to get a bound stronger than $(1+O(1/\ln^2 x)x)$ from known proofs of the Prime Number Theorem, however no bound stronger than this can be deduced purely from "PNT implies...", and by this I mean that the statement of PNT doesn't yield **any** explicit constant for the $O$, while Dusart does.

Comment: Good. Now you are complete :)